# Place buttons on each side of scrollable div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place buttons on the left and the right side of a scrollable div. See this [jsfiddle[1]](http://jsfiddle.net/y84VA/1/) where they are still wrapped. So I changed the display of `content` and `btn` to `inline-block`. See this next version of the [jsfiddle[2]](http://jsfiddle.net/y84VA/2/). That sort of worked, but the buttons are not nicely aligned. And I actually don't have any idea why. So how come and why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am confused with you saying buttons are not nicely *outlined*, but I guess you meant `align`, than you have to use `vertical-align: top;` as you are using `display: inline-block;` so your buttons are aligned to the `baseline`.

```
.btn {
    width: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/y84VA/5/)

---

You can also `float` all your elements to the `left` as [@Jarno](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20609470/1542290) suggested, but if you are going with `float` than make sure you `clear` your elements using `clear: both;` property, else you will end up with undesired positioning of your elements.

Comment: Correct, I meant aligned. I'm going for your vertical-align solution.

Comment: @netiul yes you can as it's perfectly valid to do so :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `float:left;` on `.content` and `.btn`.

Also, don't forget to put `overflow:hidden;` on your `.container`.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4WUyW/)

Comment: nah nah, overflow hidden is a cheap trick :) http://jsfiddle.net/ZdPtx/ instead use self clearing parent class.. - http://jsfiddle.net/ZdPtx/1/

Answer (score 1):

make all elements floating ~> [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y84VA/8/)

```
.content {
        width: 300px;
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        height: 40px;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 10px;
    }

   .btn {
       width: 30px;
       height: 40px;
       display: inline-block;
       float: left;
    }
```

OR you can use `vertical-align` for elements to fit each other vertically

Comment: You don't need `float` and `display: inline-block` at the same time :)

Comment: yeah. it's just a hack ^.^

Comment: Nothing like hack in this :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add float positions to each .btn. float left for the left arrow and float right

Answer (score 0):

Add the vertical align to the buttons:

```
.btn {
    width: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y84VA/7/